# How to get place basis on the city name entered using google places API?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=shivaji&bounds=19.997454,73.789803|19.997454,73.789803&key=API_KEY
This I have tried but not working using geocode as well , Is there any easier way to achieve same ?

Answer (score 0):

I got city name via below code.

"administrative_area_level_2" contains the city name and if that param is not inside the response then displaying first full address.

```
if (jsArray.length() != 0) {
   final JSONObject jsData = jsArray.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONArray jsonAddressArray = jsData.optJSONArray("address_components");
   for (int i = 0; i < jsonAddressArray.length(); i++) {
        if (jsonAddressArray.get(i).toString().contains("administrative_area_level_2")) {
            cityName = jsonAddressArray.optJSONObject(i).optString("long_name");
        }
   }
   if(TextUtils.isEmpty(address)){
      cityName = jsData.optString("formatted_address");
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rushabh, Thanks for your response.   if I select city as Ahmedabad .I want names like "Dariyapur" when I input some strings like "Dar" . is it possible to get with your suggestion ?

Comment: let me check for that

Comment: But meanwhile, Please don't share your API Key.

Comment: Change "administrative_area_level_2" with **"political"** to get "Dariyapur".

Comment: If it will helpful, then upwote my answer.